# Get Fragment View Values from FragmentActivity

Tags: android

I have a FragmentActivity with FragmentTabHost.

I have 3 Fragments for the FragmentTabHost to display tab content.

I am having multiple edittexts in 3 fragments and having a save button in FragmentActivity.

OnClick of save button in FragmentActivity, I want to get the edittext values from the 3 fragments.

How to get the values of edittext from Fragments in FragmentActivity?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You must first refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) link.

Answer (score -1):

First of all give Tag to fragments

```
Fragment1 frag1 = (Fragment1)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("frag1");
Fragment2 frag2  = (Fragment2)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("frag2");
Fragment3 frag3  = (Fragment3)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("frag3");
```

Now get your edittexts from fragments

```
EditText editText1 = frag1.getView().findViewById(R.id.Your_Edit_Text);
EditText editText2 = frag2.getView().findViewById(R.id.Your_Edit_Text);
EditText editText3 = frag3.getView().findViewById(R.id.Your_Edit_Text);
```

at last get there value

```
 String value1 = editText1.getText()
 String value2 = editText2.getText()
 String value3 = editText3.getText();
```

Comment: I tried to get the 1st fragment edittext value. Its not getting values from edittext and when I switch tabs its getting null pointer exception

Comment: ok thn ... use shared pref ... save value with OnTextChanged .. then use them on button click ... and one advice ... always show some coding part of ur work .. for better answer